# Permutations of Hamel bases of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual addition and multiplication operations as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Do there exist a Hamel basis $\{ v_i \}_{i \in I}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and a permutation $\phi:I \rightarrow I$ different from the identity map, such that $v_{\phi(i)}=cv_i$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $ i \in I$?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: The vectors in a basis are linearly independent.

Comment: I suppose you want $c\neq 1$ (and independent of $i$), otherwise I've got an easy example.

Comment: I don't see how to use your suggestion, prof. Ullrich. The fact that the vectors $\{ v_i \}$ are linearly independent implies that the eventual constant $c$ can't be rational. We can say more. Since $c^n \neq 1$ for every positive integer $n$, for every $v_i$ in our basis, the elements $v_i, cv_i, c^2 v_i, ..., c^n v_i$ are distinct elements of our basis, and so linearly independent over Q. This implies that $c$ cannot be an algebraic number. I cannot prove more than that. Do you have some other thing in mind?

Comment: Equivalently, you are asking whether there exists a transcendental number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}$ is free as a module over $\mathbb{Q}[c,c^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have such a basis $\{v_i\}$, permutation $\phi$, and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.  It is clear that every orbit of $\phi$ must be infinite, so $c$ is transcendental (since otherwise $c$ would have to be $-1$, but then $v_i$ is not linearly independent from $v_{\phi(i)}$).  Choose a set of representatives $B\subset\{v_i\}$ for the orbits of $\phi$.  Then the set $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a module over the ring $\mathbb{Q}[c,c^{-1}]$.

However, I claim that $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be free over $\mathbb{Q}[c,c^{-1}]$.  For instance, every element of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinitely divisible by $c+1$.  But since $c$ is transcendental, no nonzero element of the ring $\mathbb{Q}[c,c^{-1}]$ is infinitely divisible by $c+1$, and hence no nonzero element of any free module can be infinitely divisible by $c+1$.  Thus no such basis exists.

More generally, this argument applies with $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ replaced by *any* field extension $K\subset L$ (if $L$ contains roots of unity not in $K$, you need to use the fact that the powers of a root of unity cannot be linearly independent over $K$ since their sum is $0$).

Comment: so you can just look at the decomposition of $v_1/(c+1)$ and multiply everyone by $c+1$ to get a contradiction.